# The "await" property of "async" function sleeps after an instance - Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

I am working on a **scraper** . I am using Phantom JS along with Node JS. Phantom JS loads the page with `async` function, just like : `var status = await page.open(url)`. Sometimes, because of the slow internet the page takes longer to load and after a time the page `status` is not returned, to check while its loaded or not. And the `page.open()` sleeps, which doesn't return anything at all, and all the execution is waiting.

So, my basic question is; is there any way to keep this `page.open(url)` alive, as the execution of the rest of the code waits until the page is loaded.

**My Code is**

```
const phantom = require('phantom');

ph_instance = await phantom.create();
ph_page = await ph_instance.createPage();

var status = await ph_page.open("https://www.cscscholarship.org/");

if (status == 'success') {
  console.log("Page is loaded successfully !");
  //do more stuff
}
```

Comment: Can you please edit your title into something more sensical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment, it seems like it might be timing out (because of slow internet sometimes)... you can validate this by adding the `onResourceTimeout` method to your code (link: http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html)

It would look something like this:

```
ph_instance.onResourceTimeout = (request) => {
    console.log('Timeout caught:' + JSON.stringify(request));
};
```

And if that ends up being true, you can increase the default resource timeout settings (link: http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/settings.html) like this:

```
ph_instance.settings.resourceTimeout = 60000 // 60 seconds
```

Edit: I know the question is about phantom, but I wanted to also mention another framework I've used for scraping projects before called Puppeteer (link: https://pptr.dev/) I personally found that their API's are easier to understand and code in, and it's currently a maintained project unlike Phantom JS which is not maintained anymore (their last release was two years ago).

Comment: Yes, you are right. Few days back I got aware of that framework. But my Scrapper is almost developed, I will change it to Puppeteer when I am done with it.